# Does Google Mock count calls to mocked functions in destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, googlemock

Does Google Mock count calls to mocked functions that occur in the destructor of the object under test?

Comment: I have no idea, but I've voted your question up as it introduced me to Mock. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

I tested this and indeed calls to mocked functions within the destructor do count, i.e. you should EXPECT_CALL() them...

Comment: This behavior is also documented here: http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Mocking_Destructors